# How does powershell process return types/objects from an externally loaded DLL?

Tags: c#, powershell, com, com-object

I am a novice programmer in .NET and Powershell,

I have a small compiled .NET DLL that utilizes the Directory Services and TSUserExLib for fetching TerminalService attributes. The DLL has a one static function that returns "IADsTSUserEx". I tested the DLL and it works when returning a string, but is it possible to return the IADsTSUserEx class\object type to powershell? When I execute the static function from powershell I get nothing back, not even null. I tried it using the following commands

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\temp\test.dll"
[ABC.Class1]::getTSEntry("user@domain.com")
```

The DLL contains this code snippet:

```
DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                IADsTSUserEx tsuser = (IADsTSUserEx)result.GetDirectoryEntry().NativeObject;
                return tsuser;
```

Comment: Try running `[ABC.Class1]::getTSEntry("user@domain.com") | Get-Member` and see what that displays.  I suspect it's not that `getTSEntry` returns `$null` but rather that PowerShell just doesn't know how to format and display an `IADsTSUserEx` object.

Comment: @BACON, thanks for the response! I tried your suggestion and I get the following error: "Get-Member : No Object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet". I know that the call is executing because it will trigger exceptions for non-existing users. Seems it just doesn't know how to handle the return object so it returns nothing, not even null.. Even the statement "[ABC.Class1]::getTSEntry("user@domain.com") -eq $null" does nothing

Comment: Couldn't edit previous comment, but also wanted to state that "[ABC.Class1]::getTSPath("user@domain.com").getType() returns a BaseType of "System.MarshalByRefObject" and Name of "__ComObject"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your method returns a COM object and PowerShell isn't directly exposing its methods and properties to you, you'll need to access them with reflection and the [`Type.InvokeMember` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/66btctbe.aspx):

```
$entry = [ABC.Class1]::getTSEntry("user@domain.com");
$entryType = $entry.GetType();
$binder = $null;
$someMethodParameters = @('Parameter #1', 12345, 'Parameter #3');
$someMethodResult = $entryType.InvokeMember('SomeMethod', 'Public, Instance, InvokeMethod', $binder, $entry, $someMethodParameters);
$somePropertyValue = $entryType.InvokeMember('SomeProperty', 'Public, Instance, GetProperty', $binder, $entry, $null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion however I get an error "COM Object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used". I'm assuming this means the DirectoryEntry.NativeObject. Probably some object that was disposed on the callback from the DLL maybe? Regardless, I'll just do things the wrong way and translate each Property to return a string instead of  returning the whole TSUserEX class.